# Resolving errors in std headers when using std methods/classes incorrectly

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I am new to C++ and I frequently come into a situation where I get a compile time error while using `std` templated classes/containers/methods.

Most of the time, error is shown inside of some `std` header file that I don't include directly. Furthermore, offending line is always inside of some method that I don't call directly.

So I have no idea which line of my code eventually leads to that error. In other words, I can't determine the call stack (if it can be called so in this case) that causes the error.

Is there an efficient "debugging" process that I can use when determining offending code in case of errors like this?

This is an example of such error. I will figure this error out somehow, so I am not interested in this particular error, but rather in more general solution to problems such as this.

> Error C2280   'MyNamespace::MyClass &MyNamespace::MyClass::operator
>   =(const MyNamespace::MyClass &)': attempting to reference a deleted function  MyLib   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   14.0\vc\include\utility   53

Comment: Sure you can, there's usually more information what you're referring to, e.g. like deleted copy constructors of `std::ofstream` or alike.

Comment: Compile often, so that you know which change introduced the error

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because you have used the standard library incorrectly.  Sometimes it's many pages of errors but your code error will be in there somewhere.  It's one of the many challenges of using C++ - to descramble these error messages and figure out what you've done wrong.  The more adapt you get at using the standard libraries, the better you get at figuring out these errors.  It's all part of getting things right at compile time so you don't have to deal with these errors at run time.  Run time errors can be many degrees of magnitude harder to solve.